# Create DB view where each row takes value(s) from previous one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB table like this (other columns are omitted)

```
date          | change

2018/10/10    |  +8
2018/10/31    |  -5
2018/11/01    |  +3
2018/11/03    |  -2
```

I want to create a DB View from that table that display this

```
date          | change  | cumulative
2018/10/10    |  +8     |  8
2018/10/31    |  -5     |  3
2018/11/01    |  +3     |  6
2018/11/03    |  -2     |  4
```

the cumulative, which is the cumulative of previous entry (ordered by date) plus/minus change of current entry

**Is there a cheap way (in terms of computation) that could create such view?**

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? If it is 8.0.2 and above, you can look at window functions with Frames. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html

Comment: initial value is 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT t1.Date, t1.Change, SUM(t2.Change) AS Cumalative
FROM YourTable t1
INNER JOIN YourTable t2 on t1.Date >= t2.Date
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.Change
ORDER BY t1.Date
```

Comment: This tag are `mysql`.. Your answer are `sql server` way to do

Comment: I see both tags. Not sure which one he actually needs

Comment: remove [] and using bactick ``.. So the query will valid.. and remove dbo..

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       sum(change) over (order by date) as cumulative
from t;
```

In earlier versions, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.change) from t t2 where t2.date <= t.date) as cumulative
from t;
```

This will work in a view and can take advantage of an index on `(date, change)`.

This version is probably not as efficient as using variables in the older versions of MySQL, but it should be better than a `join`/`group by` solution.